# React Native - why does my image button flash on Android?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a simple image button, which changes its image onTouchStart and onRelease. On iOs, it works like expected, but on Android the button flashes, when the image changes.
It looks like, if the image has to be loaded again everytime I'm touching it.

```html
class MyApp extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={ styles.container }>
                <ImageButton
                    style={ styles.button }/>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
class ImageButton extends React.Component {

    constructor(props: {}) {
        super(props);

        this.image = {
            normal: require('./img/button.png'),
            highlight: require('./img/button-touched.png')
        };

        this.state = {
            image: this.image.normal
        };
    }

    onTouchStart() {
    
        // do some stuff
        
        // set the highlighted image
        this.setState({
            image: this.image.highlight
        });
    }

    onTouchEnd() {
        this.setState({
            image: this.image.normal
        })
    }

    onTouchCancel() {
        this.setState({
            image: this.image.normal
        });
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        this.setState({
            image: nextProps.image.normal
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={ this.props.style }
                  onStartShouldSetResponder={ () => true }
                  onResponderGrant={ this.onTouchStart.bind(this) }
                  onResponderRelease={ this.onTouchEnd.bind(this) }
                  onResponderTerminate={ this.onTouchCancel.bind(this) }
                  onResponderReject={ this.onTouchCancel.bind(this) }>
                <Image style={ styles.image } source={ this.state.image } resizeMode="stretch" />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#E4E4E4',
    },
    button: {
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('schwein', () => Schwein);
```

Answer (score 1):

Images are implemented slightly differently on each platform afaik so this indeed might be happening. I wolud suggesting creating component with these images loaded on start and then control its visibility using opacity defined by styles. It should work as u expected, without flashing.